# Solution verification on Folland Real Analysis, Problem 2.16

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

---

**Problem** If $f \in L^+$ and $\int f < \infty$, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $E \in \mathscr{M}$ such that $\mu(E) < \infty$ and $\int_E f > \left( \int f \right) - \epsilon$.

---

**New Solution**

Let $g_n = \chi_{E_n}$, where $E_n = f^{-1} \left( \left(\frac{1}{n}, n \right] \right)$. Since $ \int f \ge \frac{1}{n} \mu(E_n) = \infty$, $\mu(E_n) < \infty$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Also it is trivial that $f_n = f \cdot g_n$ increases to $f$ as $n \to \infty$.

Now we apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem to obtain the following result: $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n = \int f.$$

Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$\left( \int f \right) - \epsilon < \int f_n = \int_{E_n} f,$$
and the theorem follows.

---

I corrected my proof. How does it look? Is it okay now?

Thanks in advance.

---

> **Solution with error** (It is not assumed that $\mu([-n, n])$ is finite.)
>
> Let $g_n = \chi_{[-n, n]}$. The sequence $f_n = f \cdot g_n$ increases to $f$ as $n \to \infty$, and thus we can apply the Monotone Convergence Theorem to obtain the following result. $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \int f_n = \int f.$$
>
> Then for every $\epsilon > 0$ there exists an $n \in \Bbb{N}$ such that $$\left( \int f \right) - \epsilon < \int f_n = \int_{[-n, n]} f,$$
> and the theorem follows.

Comment: It looks good but you still have to justify that $\mu([-n,n]) <\infty$

Comment: Are you working in $\mathbb{R}$ with the Borel sets and the Lebesgue measure? Add this information in the question body.

Comment: What is $L^+$??

Comment: The original problem was about an arbitrary measure, but I thought it was the Lebesgue measure. There *is* a major flaw in my solution, I think. Thank you all guys!

Comment: @copper.hat $L^+$ denotes the set of every measurable function in which the range lies inside $[0, \infty]$ in Folland Real Analysis.

Comment: @Salcio Snoop I corrected my solution. Is it okay now?

Comment: Minor wording change, you have shown that $E_n$ has finite measure, not assumed...

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks! English is not my first language and such advice helps me a lot.

Comment: @SULee English **is** my first language and I still struggle to express things correctly :-).